# iMovie crossfading audio automatically

Tags: imovie

I'm not sure if this is the right site for this question; please point me in the right direction if it isn't :)

I literally started using iMovie today so I have no idea what anything's called so bear with me.
I have two audio clips next to each other in iMovie. I want one audio clip to end when one image changes to another image, and the next audio clip to start immediately thereafter.

For some reason, when I place these (disconnected) audio files next to each other, iMovie does a automatic crossfade between them that ruins the effect I was going for. I have put those fader circle thingies at the extreme ends of the audio clips so as to avoid any kind of fade, but iMovie still adds it by default. I have no idea how to remove this, I can't find anything in settings that would work.

I'm probably missing something super obvious. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too, and I managed to find a small workaround - When the audio clips touch/immediately follow on from eachother, they will blend together, but if you change either the clips durations by even a tiny amount, they'll disconnect and won't mix.